# Trying to make a single "shockwave" ripple through a mesh, triggered multiple times by audio. Seems like I'm missing a simple solution

Tags: modifiers, displacement, audio, actions, distort

I'm doing a music video and I'm trying to figure out how to have a shockwave ripple outwards from a certain location on for example a mesh plane, but triggered by audio.  Picture a basic wave modifier on a plane, creating circles of distortion that spread outwards from a point.  I want that, except triggered by the kick drum.

Pretty good reference here at 1:10:  https://vimeo.com/279951059
On the snare drum hit, there's a single fast ripple.  That's basically what I'm trying to do, triggered by audio.

I've tried using the audio as a driver on some of the wave modifier parameters, for example controlling the height of the effect, but the problem is that I need the wave to start in the center at a certain time.

One other thing I tried was using the dynamic paint wave simulation, and having the audio trigger an invisible brush object that would strike the plane in time with the music, creating waves.  It works but I really want more consistent, controlled, pronounced waves like you can get with the wave modifier.

I figure there must be an easy solution to this.

One thing I was imagining was using the displacement modifier, making an image sequence of a ripple, and having the image sequence triggered by the audio.

I guess the core problem is that I don't know how to get the audio to trigger an action (as opposed to just mimicking the values from the audio keyframes).  If I could keyframe the effect I'm looking for, and then have each kick drum hit trigger that set of keyframes, that would be the solution to a lot of other things I'm trying to do as well.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?  Something with the NLA editor?

Thanks for your help!